# Getting Result for Counted and Not Counted Record

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 3 tables.

tags, posts and poststags

The poststags table hold tags.id and posts.id so I can assign multiple tags to a post.

I wanted to count the total number of tags used including zero (0) count.

Sample result:

- tag A - count = 5
- tag B - count = 10
- tag C - count = 0
- tag D - count = 25

etc...

All I can think of is create two statements:

```
SELECT * FROM tags;
```

Then while traversing each record from the first statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(pt.tagid) FROM poststags pt
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.id = pt.postid
WHERE p.published = 'yes' AND pt.tagid = /* current tag id from first statement */
```

Is it possible to create 1 single SQL statement instead of 2 and get the same result?

Comment: You probably want `COUNT(DISTINCT pt.tagid)`. But your query doesn't make sense. Why `LEFT JOIN` if you anyway filter on `published`? You may as well do `INNER JOIN`. What exact filtering on `posts` do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `left join` as follows:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name,
       COUNT(p.id) as num_of_post
FROM tags t
Left join poststags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.id = pt.postid And p.published = 'yes'
```